# How to remove error messages when searching recursively for a string?

Tags: linux, io-redirection, search, string

I use

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 grep -i searchstring
```

to search recursively for a string. But it also gives me error messages like "permission denied". How can I avoid such error messages and only see results?

Answer (score 8):

Redirect standard error to /dev/null.  I.e.

```
find -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n 10 grep -i searchstring 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I set an alias for  `find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 grep -i searchstring`. Alias is: "mysearch". I search it like this: `mysearch searchstring`. How will I set your command to an alias? because, in your command `searchstring` is inside the command, not in the end.

Comment: A bit dumb but this would do the trick: `find -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n 10 grep -i searchstring 2>/dev/null | grep -i searchstring`

Answer (score 0):

If the error messages come from find (e.g. because there's a directory you can't traverse, redirect its errors to `/dev/null`.

```
find -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | …
```

If the error messages come from grep (e.g. because some files are unreadable), redirect its errors to `/dev/null`, or pass the `-s` option to tell it to ignore unreadable files.

```
xargs -0 grep -s -i searchstring /dev/null
```

There's no point in limiting the number of files passed together to `grep`. But you should add `/dev/null` so that `grep` always sees at least two files, otherwise `grep` omits the file name in its output if it has only one file argument. With GNU grep or Busybox (i.e. Linux or Cygwin), you can use the `-H` option instead.